# Badge counter on launcher icon in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, counter, badge

I am trying to implement badger count on app launcher icon in flutter for all android based devices. I've tried flutter_app_badger and flutter_dynamic_icon  as well but both of them aren't compatible with android. I wan't a unamious solution it's awesome if it works both for android or ios as well.
I am trying to find solutions but there isn't enough data present. Onesignal push notification I am using for the app provides default badge count but it's not in all devices either.
Please help me with the situation.

```
setLauncherNumber()async{
  // set batch number
  try {
    print('LauncherBadge inside try');
    // FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(10);
    await FlutterDynamicIcon.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(93);
    print('LauncherBadge Success');
  } catch (e) {
    print('LauncherBadge error $e');
  }
}
```

flutter_app_badger and flutter_dynamic_icon arent compatible with all devices

Comment: On Android, no official API exists to show a badge in the launcher. But some devices (Samsung, HTC...) support the feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this package [flutter_app_badger: ^1.5.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_badger)

```
import 'package:flutter_app_badger/flutter_app_badger.dart';

FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried this plugin, but it's not compatible with every device. Also, it doesn't work with IOS devices either. I might be missing something and am kind of a beginner in this field. I am looking for a unanimous solution to be compatible with all devices including IOS. Please suggest me ....